# Better library to handle null values compared to JSONObject

Tags: java, spring, jackson, org.json

Code :

```
String jsonStr = "{\"key\": null}";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonStr, Map.class);


if(jsonObject.get("random") == null) { // false
    log.info("JSONObject");
}

if(map.get("random") == null) {        // true
    log.info("map");
}
```

Seems `JSONObject` is not able to handle the `null` values as a `Map` does, it's converting the `null` in `jsonStr` to `"JSONObject.NULL"` value.

Though JSONObject is internally using Map<String, Object>, but still this is a different way of null handling is present in the library. I don't know if there are other caveats in the library or not. We have caught this while dev testing. Seeing this behaviour we are thinking if we could use some other libraries than org.json.

Are there any better libraries than **org.json.JSONObject**, which matches it's efficiency and still doesn't have these caveats ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not converting the null value into a `JSONObject.NULL`?

Comment: (Please don't use block quotes when you're not actually quoting anything.)

Comment: use `isNull(key)` instead of `get(key)` as it will return something always (or throw an error if the key isn't there). And while **you** may find it strange, for the library authors it isn't. There is a specific value created to check (also to be able to determine null and empty). So instead of complaining about a library you might want to read the documentation on how you should use it, instead of making assumptions on how things work.

Comment: @JonSkeet, it's converting null values to JSONObject.NULL, but not java's ```null```. With this we have to bind the logic to much with ```JSONObject.NULL```, wherever we do null checks.

Comment: @M.Deinum, the common assumption was that it would return null, as it's using Map<Object, String> internally which also returns null, but after facing this issue we realised that, there is a different NULL created in JSONObject to handle this.

Comment: "it's converting null values to JSONObject.NULL" - right, so that's not *at all* the same as "it's converting the null in jsonStr to "null" string type in java". It sounds like it's behaving as intended, and allowing you to easily differentiate between a key being absent and it having an explicit null value. That sounds like a feature rather than a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't interact with JSON objects directly, I prefer to work "in Java" to use all of the language features and use JSON only as a form of serialization format to communicate with other applications (think about calling a REST endpoint from a language that does not have the "null" concept).

For JSONJava's JSONObject null handling I think it is a deliberate choice by the developers to implement the Null Object Pattern. If you look at the [JSONObject](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html) javadoc you will see that it deserializes nulls as [NULL](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#NULL) objects such that `NULL.equals(null)` is true. So to make your example work it is sufficient to use "equals()" method instead of "=="

Comment: Yes we have to make this trade off, we could use the java object as well, but fields in the objects are 100-200, and we have to do de-serialization to object and serialize to string to send over network. It seems that JSON string to a JSONObject is faster than converting it to a Java object and vice-versa. So what choice would be better here.

Comment: I personally never used it myself but i always heard that for Java the fastest JSON serializer/deserializer is [jsoniter](https://jsoniter.com/). Judging by their benchmark it is like 3 times faster than Jackson. Maybe you could give it a try and see if it fits in your project. If you want to stick with JSONObject instead doing JSONObject.NULL.equals(jsonObject.get("random")) should do the trick.